# Can I integrate and use admob ads in an Android project using Kotlin?

Tags: android, admob, kotlin

I have an android project that's written with Kotlin. can i add admob ads to it using kotlin?

Comment: Why not? You can call java code from kotlin, and kotlin code from java freely.

Comment: @Ufkoku Could you please add some sprcific code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do that by initializing the following vars inside your class

```
internal lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
internal lateinit var adRequest : AdRequest
```

And Start an adrequest inside  override fun onCreate with the following codes

```
mInterstitialAd =  InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = " YOUR INTERSTITIAL ID";
adRequest =  AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {

@Override    public  override fun onAdLoaded() {
    requestNewInterstitial()
  }
};
```

Visit this link for the complete admob use and integration using Kotlin : [Tutorial](http://www.nulledmobileapps.com/2017/05/integrate-and-use-admob-ads-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    lateinit var interstitialAd: InterstitialAd
    lateinit var adRequest: AdRequest   

    interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    interstitialAd.adUnitId = getString(R.string.admob_interstitial)
    adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)

    interstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                interstitialAd.show()
            }

        }


    }
```